# How can i find details of LOCALITY, PARTITIONED,UNIQUENESS in postgres same as we get from oracle's USER_PART_INDEXES

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, postgresql-9.5

Can someone help me to get the columns `LOCALITY`, `PARTITIONED`, `UNIQUENESS` in postgres same as we get from oracle's `USER_PART_INDEXES` which displays the object-level partitioning information for the partitioned indexes?

I tried using `pg_indexes` in postgres, but couldn't find `LOCALITY`, `PARTITIONED`, `UNIQUENESS` details.

```
oracle : 
SELECT  I.INDEX_NAME INDEX_NAME
FROM    USER_PART_INDEXES PI,USER_INDEXES I
WHERE   I.TABLE_NAME    = test
AND     LOCALITY        = 'LOCAL'
AND     PARTITIONED     = 'YES'
AND     UNIQUENESS      = 'NONUNIQUE'
AND     INDEX_TYPE      <> P_EXCLUDE_TYPE
AND     I.TABLE_NAME    = PI.TABLE_NAME
AND     I.INDEX_NAME    = PI.INDEX_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL isn't Oracle and your life will be easier if you don't try to treat their system catalogues as the same.

These two system tables are what you will want, but don't just assume the behaviours are the same in both systems:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has no global indexes (yet), so all indexes on partitioned tables are "local" indexes.

The uniqueness of an index is stored in [`pg_index.indisunique`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html)

To find all non-unique indexes for a specific table in Postgres you can do:

```
select ic.relname as index_name
from pg_index ix 
  join pg_class ic on ix.indexrelid = ic.oid
where ix.indrelid = 'test'::regclass
  and not ix.indisunique;
```

Comment: How to find out the column PARTITIONED to check whether table is partioned or not ?

Comment: @Sanjum Are you talking about table inheritance? Postgres 9.5 did not have proper partitioning